# How to remove random rows from a matrix in Fortran90

Tags: arrays, memory, fortran, sigabrt

OK so here is the problem. In my assignment I should create a (3,1000) matrix and after I created it I should delete RANDOMLY 271 rows of the matrix. At the end I should obtain a (3,729) Matrix with all the initial values except the one I deleted corresponding to the random numbers.

To do so I wrote this script where
**Mc=1000
N=729**

```
h=1
do a=1, (Mc-N)

   call random_number(rand_num)
   rand_num=int(rand_num*Mc)-1
   !print*, rand_num

   do b=1, Mc

      if (b /= rand_num) then

      NMatrix(:,h) = Matrix(:,b)

      h=h+1

      else

      h=h

      endif
    enddo
enddo
```

But when I run it it reports me this error: `Program receiver signal SIGABRT : Process abort signal.`
What should I do? Please it's really important

I know there is some problem with the do loops and the memory of the arrays, but I cannot get to the point. Can you please ask me?

Comment: In your first pass through the b loop you have added 999 rows (at least) to the new matrix. In the next pass you have added another 999 rows ... and so on. You will run out of matrix or memory quite quickly. Also, "h=h" is an unnecessary statement.

Comment: Please post a full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are several obvious flaws in your code, but the way to correct them depends on pieces of code that are not present (e.g. how the matrices are declared).

Comment: By convention, a matrix element `a(i,j)` indicates the _i_-th row and _j_-th column. In your case, you are removing 271 columns and not 271 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example ouput of what you are asking for (I think).

```text
rows=3, cols=1000
1.000 2.000 3.000 4.000 5.000 6.000 7.000 8.000 9.000 10.00 11.00 12.00 ...
1001. 1002. 1003. 1004. 1005. 1006. 1007. 1008. 1009. 1010. 1011. 1012. ...
2001. 2002. 2003. 2004. 2005. 2006. 2007. 2008. 2009. 2010. 2011. 2012. ...

rows=3, cols=729
1.000 3.000 4.000 9.000 10.00 11.00 12.00 13.00 14.00 16.00 17.00 19.00 ...
1001. 1003. 1004. 1009. 1010. 1011. 1012. 1013. 1014. 1016. 1017. 1019. ...
2001. 2003. 2004. 2009. 2010. 2011. 2012. 2013. 2014. 2016. 2017. 2019. ...
```

Note that by convention, the 1st index is the rows, and the 2nd index is the columns. So you are asking to remove **271 columns** from the matrix.

I decided to use an array of index values `indx=[1,2,3,4 .. n]`, which I shuffle randomly, then slice off the last 271 values (keep `n` entries) and then sort back to increasing order.

Finally, the result is essentially `NMatrix(:,:) = Matrix(:, indx)` or in my case I call them `a` and `b` in my function.

```
function RemoveRandomColumns(a,n_col) result(b)
real, intent(in) :: a(:,:)
integer, intent(in) :: n_col
real, allocatable :: b(:,:)
integer :: i,j,n,m,t
integer, allocatable :: indx(:)
real :: u !used in shuffle part
m = size(a, 1)
n = size(a, 2)
! must remove m-n_col columns from a
allocate(indx(n))
indx = [ (i,i=1,n) ]
! indx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,..,n]

! suffle the index
call RANDOM_SEED()
do i=1, n
    call RANDOM_NUMBER(u)
    j = 1 + floor(u*(n-1))
    t = indx(i)
    indx(i) = indx(j)
    indx(j) = t
end do
! indx = [18,10,3,16,21,...]

! take only n_col items
indx = indx(1:n_col)
! indx = [18,10,3,...]

! sort the index
do i=1, n_col
    do j=1, i-1
        if(indx(i)<indx(j)) then
            t = indx(i)
            indx(i) = indx(j)
            indx(j) = t
        end if
    end do
end do
! indx = [2,3,4,6,7,9,..,n]

! now slice the array to get the resukt
allocate(b(m,n_col))
do j=1, m
    b(j,:) = a(j,indx)
end do
end function
```

and the sample code to test the above is

```
program FortranProgram1
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none

integer, parameter :: Mc = 1000, n = 729

! Variables
real :: matrix(3, Mc)
real :: reduced(3, n)
integer :: i,j

do j=1, 3
    do i=1, Mc
        matrix(j,i) = real(Mc*(j-1)+i)
    end do
end do

print '("rows=",g0,", cols=",g0)', size(matrix,1), size(matrix,2)
print '(*(g0.4," "))', matrix(1,1:12), "..."
print '(*(g0.4," "))', matrix(2,1:12), "..."
print '(*(g0.4," "))', matrix(3,1:12), "..."

print *, ""

reduced = RemoveRandomColumns(matrix, n)

print '("rows=",g0,", cols=",g0)', size(reduced,1), size(reduced,2)
print '(*(g0.4," "))', reduced(1,1:12), "..."
print '(*(g0.4," "))', reduced(2,1:12), "..."
print '(*(g0.4," "))', reduced(3,1:12), "..."

contains

function RemoveRandomColumns(a,n_col) result(b)
...
end function

end program
```