# Unique random numbers series in fortran

Tags: random, fortran, random-seed

I have this problem in Fortran where I need to generate a sequence of random numbers (precisely, 729 random numbers between 1 and 1000) and to do I use the intrinsic function `random_number()`.

The problem, of course, is that it returns *pseudorandom numbers* and it happens to often that I get same values repeated. I'm not an expert in programming with Fortran, but how can I get 729 *unique* random numbers without repetitions? Can someone help me?

Comment: Getting duplicate random numbers has nothing to do with pseudo-randomness; a cryptographic RNG can product duplicates. Indeed, if it couldn't it wouldn't be random. You're looking for a [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), not a random number.

Comment: There are `1,056,964,609` unique real-32bit numbers in the interval `(0,1)`. The odds of getting two identical real-32bit numbers among 729 tries are even less than that of an airplane falling from the sky. Please provide a minimal working example of what you have done so far. I agree with the above comment you are likely after unique random shuffling of an integer set, not random `real` numbers as your question states.

Comment: Hopefully Marta realized that in the other answer John just gave her a rope to hang herself on and she wants to genuinely finish the homework herself only with some help. The teachers are very likely to know Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please show what have tried so far.

Comment: Create a logical array of 1000 elements, initialised as .TRUE.. Keep generating random numbers in the range 1-1000 until you have been able to mark 1000-729=271 of them as .FALSE.. Then use this as a mask array in your other thread. Re-read this comment and remove the magic numbers. No shuffle is required.

Comment: @lastchance : that works for smaller sizes I suppose, so 729 out of 1000 would fall under it. Once you're up to maybe `250,000` or so using a proper shuffling algo is probably preferable. I tried both for using `awk` to shuffle rows in a file. The true/false approach became REALLY slow towards the end when trying to shuffle 12.5 million rows because it kept hitting false….false….false…. nonstop

Comment: If you want a genuine shuffle then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle but here you only have to pick 271 out of 1000 (choose the SMALLER  of 729 and 1000-729). You are highly unlikely to see a large sequence of already-chosen/already-chosen/already-chosen that way. For Marta's problem - see her other thread - the order of random numbers is irrelevant. I stand by my contention - you DON'T need a full shuffle.

Comment: Did you call `RANDOM_SEED()` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how you can in an inelegant way solve your problem.

```
program p
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: n = 10
   logical :: a(n) = .false.
   integer b(n), cnt
   real x
   cnt = 1
   do
      call random_number(x)
      b(cnt) = n * x + 1
      if (.not. a(b(cnt))) then
         if (b(cnt) > n) cycle
         a(b(cnt)) = .true.
         cnt = cnt + 1
         if (cnt > n) exit
      end if
   end do
   print '(*(1X,I0))', b
end program p
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ cat the_chosen.f90 
Program possibly_homework

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64
  
  Implicit None( Type, External )

  Integer, Parameter :: from      = 1000
  Integer, Parameter :: to_choose =  729
  
  Real( wp ) :: rand

  Integer, Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: the_many
  Integer, Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: the_chosen

  Integer :: the_chosen_one
  Integer :: unit
  Integer :: i

  Allocate( the_many( 1:from ) )
  the_many = [ ( i, i = 1, from ) ]

  Allocate( the_chosen( 1:0 ) )

  Do i = 1, to_choose
     Call Random_number( rand )
     the_chosen_one = 1 + Int( Size( the_many ) * rand )
     the_chosen     = [ the_chosen, the_many( the_chosen_one ) ]
     the_many       = [ the_many( :the_chosen_one - 1 ), the_many( the_chosen_one + 1: ) ] 
  End Do

  Open( newunit = unit, file = 'the_chosen.dat' )
  Do i = 1, Size( the_chosen )
     Write( unit, '( i0, t20, i0 )' ) i, the_chosen( i )
  End Do
  Close( unit )
  
End Program possibly_homework
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2018 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g the_chosen.f90 -o the_chosen
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ ./the_chosen 
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ head the_chosen.dat
1                  303
2                  916
3                  414
4                  452
5                  116
6                  962
7                  392
8                  675
9                  153
10                 458
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ sort +1 -n the_chosen.dat  | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq -D
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: Ian, your solution seem much more elegant than mine.  I did not want to spend time thinking about an array solution.  I do however worry about the performance impact of the reallocation on assignment.

Comment: No worries. I don't claim performance. I wanted to make it not only elegant but something the OP might learn from if they have to describe it to whoever set the work. If you want performance simply swap the chosen one with the end of the list, and reduce the list length by one - no need to reallocate. But IMO the above is cleaner as an educational example.

Answer (score 0):

Order not important (as per Marta's question at [How to remove random rows from a matrix in Fortran90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470847/how-to-remove-random-rows-from-a-matrix-in-fortran90) ). No shuffle required.

```
program test
   implicit none
   integer Nmax, Nsample, Nchoose
   logical start
   logical, allocatable :: mask(:)
   integer cnt, i
   real r

   Nmax = 10       ! or 1000
   Nsample = 7     ! or 729
   
   start = .false.
   Nchoose = Nsample
   if ( Nsample > Nmax / 2 ) then
      start = .true.         ! go for the SMALLER likelihood of already taken
      Nchoose = Nmax - Nsample
   end if

   allocate ( mask(Nmax) )
   mask = start

   cnt = 0
   call random_seed()
   do while ( cnt < Nchoose )
      call random_number( r )
      i = 1 + r * Nmax
      if ( mask(i) .eqv. start ) then
         mask(i) = .not. mask(i)
         cnt = cnt + 1
      end if
   end do

   do i = 1, Nmax
      if ( mask(i) ) write( *, * ) i
   end do

end program test
```